# What is the origin of the place name "Abbottabad?"

Tags: etymology, loanwords

We know that Abbottabad is named after [Major James Abbott](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Abbott_%28Indian_Army_officer%29), an officer in the Indian Army who founded the town. But where does the "...abad" come from? Does it have any relationship to the English word *abode*?

Comment: I edited this to include the question from the Language Log post about the relationship to English *abode*. Otherwise the question was in danger of being closed as off-topic.

Comment: Talk Abbotabad place to hide.

Comment: +1 @glowcoder haha Talk Abbotabad place to hide twice! http://emptywheel.firedoglake.com/2011/05/03/isi-raided-abbottabad-compound-in-2003-looking-for-abu-furaj-al-libi/

Answer (score 13):

I am an native Urdu speaker. This word is combination of Abbot and Abad. Abbot can be the name of person.

*Abad* used in terms of to populate, or get settled on location, or residence or to reside.
 Another word is *abadi* which means population or a place where some population exist. i.e. *Abadi* of Pakistan is 160 million.

There are many other cities with suffix *abad* like, Islamabad, Muzaffarabad, Khroatabad etc etc.

So Islamabad will mean something like residence of Islam (it can be a name of person as well)
Abbotabad will mean like place populated by Abbot, or residence of Abbot.

Answer (score 10):

This was just discussed in depth on [Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3127). After a long discussion giving a variety of different perspectives on the etymological roots of *-abad*, we get this conclusion:

> So where does all of this leave us?  On the one hand, the experts are not entirely agreed upon the etymological derivation of the Persian place name ending -aabaad, but it most likely comes from an Iranian root paa ("protect"). On the other hand, the English word "abode" appears to come from a Proto-Indo-European root *bheidh ("stay, wait").  In any event, I have not discovered any etymological or historical evidence indicating that Persian -aabaad and English "abode" are related.

Comment: +1 Any connection with Germanic *-burg*? It begins with a labial occlusive as well, and I think it also means something similar to "protect"...?

Comment: @Cerberus, I haven't done any research on it, but initially I'm *very* doubtful that there's any relationship, since the Germanic root has an added -r-, and the final consonants don't match.

Comment: @JSBangs: Yeah, that is what I thought... there is a small chance that *-burg* consists of two roots... but I have no idea, really.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned that there are a lot of cities in the region ending with *abad*, the two most prominent ones being Hyderabad, India and Jalalabad, Afghanistan.

Comment: Just to note, I've been talking with a friend of mine from the area and he seems to think it comes from Urdu, originating from Persian to mean 'abode, town or settlement', as in Islamabad meaning 'abode / settlement of Islam. I'm digging a little more.

Comment: @MrD, did you read the LL article? They cover that angle pretty thoroughly.

Comment: @JSBangs Not yet, no, just catching up.

Comment: I read through that article. One thing it fails to mention is that Persian *is also Indo-European*, so they could well still be related words. One talk with a good linguist would have straightened this out. The ancient relationship between English, Persian, and Sanscrit *is what started the field of linguistics in the first place*, so this is a very well-studied language relationship.

Comment: @TED, I'm sure that the professional linguists at Language Log know that Persian is an Indo-European language, though they don't make this explicit. Their conclusion asserts implicitly that the Persian root *paa* does not relate to the PIE root *bheidh-*, which it would have to in order for the words to be related.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: The root "paa" meaning "protect" also exists in Sanskrit (not just Persian), and I suspect it probably goes back to PIE.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, yes, but it doesn't go back to the same root as English *abode*.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: I agree. The linked Language Log post covers things pretty thoroughly, but it is worth including the relevant bits in an answer here: that *-aabaad* is from Persian meaning "populated/inhabited/cultivated place", and that is a common ending in place names in the region, like Hyderabad, Ahmedabad, Allahabad, Faisalabad, Jalalabad… and even Leninabad, Stalinabad….

Answer (score 4):

From: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbottabad_(poem))

Etymology: The name of the city is a compound containing two words, Abbott and Abad.

> Abad: a place of living.

But this seems interesting, since, in Spanish

> Abad: Abbott.

From: Google Translate

Answer (score 4):

here's an (and probably an easier) entry about [**آباد**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A2%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AF)

> Per Lubotsky, from Common Iranian
>   *āpāta-, ultimately from Proto-Indo-European [*peh₂- (“to
>   protect”)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aProto-Indo-European/peh%E2%82%82-), whence also Persian پاییدن
>   (pāyīdan).
>
> [Commonly compared to Sanskrit आवास
>   (ā-vāsa, “abode, residence,
>   dwelling”)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF), which is most likely from
>   Sanskrit root √vas (“to dwell, live,
>   stop, stay”).

here's the entry on [*peh₂-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aProto-Indo-European/peh%E2%82%82-)

> Semantic shift from "protector"
>   towards "shepherd, herder" can be seen
>   in many branches, signifying the
>   importance of herding. Unusual is the
>   o-grade root in Greek ποιμήν (poimḗn,
>   “shepherd, herdsman”), where the
>   abstract nomina agentis suffix *-men
>   usually binds e-grade, but that hardly
>   seems sufficient to reconstruct *h₃ in
>   the root and to separate it from
>   *peh₂-.

Can we find a word that has the same meaning of "abad" via "vasati"? Well, you could through one of the descendants in Hindi बस्ती (bastī)

> बस्ती • (bastī) f., Urdu spelling بستی
>
> 1. settlement, village, small town

so although you'd end up with with -abad that means city and bastī that means a small town (and arguably - an abode) - they're probably not related.

Comment: Per Lubotsky, from Common Iranian *āpāta-, ultimately from Proto-Indo-European *peh₂- (“to protect”), whence also Persian پاییدن (pāyīdan).
What does apata mean?

Answer (score 2):

-Abad comes from Hindi/Urdu word which means 'populated'. 'Abadi' mean population. There are many cities in the Indian Subcontinent and also Afghanistan(e.g. Jalalabad) ending with -abad.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This answer was already given by LifeH2O almost three years ago; to agree with it, you should use the "upvote" button to the left of that post, rather than posting a new answer that repeats it. I would encourage you to visit the [site tour](http://english.stackexcange.com/tour) and [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.